# SSISDB not found and can not create New catalog in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

I just installed SQL Server 2012, I want to create a catalog in Integration Services Catalog in order to obtain SSISDB database but I got the following error

Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you using a later standalone download version of SSMS then this may occur - 

https://krutikasuchak.wordpress.com/2018/01/16/ssis-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-invalid-object-name-sys-trusted_assemblies/

Try a 2012 version of SSMS and try again

Comment: Thank u @Mazhar it worked with ssms 2012, I had ssms 2017

Comment: @Mazhar Can you write that up as an answer so it is not lost in comments?

Comment: @JacobH Done so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem with using the standalone SSMS version (v 2017) against an older SQL version (in this example 2012)

If you using a later standalone download version of SSMS then [this may occur](https://krutikasuchak.wordpress.com/2018/01/16/ssis-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-invalid-object-name-sys-trusted_assemblies/) -

So instead use the SSMS that is installed as part of the SQL installation ad try again